# how to render html page with size of 10MB bit faster

Tags: html, performance, rendering

I have few tasks that run in the background which:

- collects data,
- make a table with hyperlinks of each task's data,
- hyperlinks are into the same page at the bottom,
- colour the data based on the needs

The data is bit big, like about 10MB file size after finishing above tasks (html page contents are just texts and no media in it). The file size can even go up to 30MB.

The data collection part takes a while because of the nature of the task itself, hence I begin with providing initial starting page which then keeps refreshing every 3 seconds adding latest additions to the bottom of the page.

Now, as that progress (and as file size keeps increasing from KB to MB) obviously the webpage rendering beings to slow down and down.

Is there any way to speedup page rendering please? Any tips is highly appreciated and many thanks in advance.